# Font awesome icons showing in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE 10

Tags: asp.net, font-awesome

I have got an ASP.Net application that makes use of *Font Awesome* icons. The icons show up fine in Chrome and in Firefox but do not display in *IE 10* at all. If I test the application locally then they do display in all browsers including *IE*, but for some reason when I deploy the site to the web server (Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7) they are not showing. Has anyone experienced this before and know how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is IE10 showin the page in a compatibility view?
Or you have a problem that IIS is not specifiying the corect mime type.

Comment: I did check that and no, it is not in compatibility view.

Comment: can you post a screen of the network activity in IE?
I had maybe similar problem, when resources didn't load becouse invalid mime type specified by the server.

Comment: You were 100% right with that last comment. The mime type for .woff was not specified on the server. Thanks, ErikS. :) Put that in your answer and I will give you the credit for the correct answer.

Comment: Done. Had the problem on a SharePoint Site :)

Comment: Glad you could help point me in the right direction. Thanks. :)